# Using RInno package for deploying rshiny app locally

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting the following error message after running the below line:

```
install_inno()
Error in domain %>% file.path("jrsoftware/issrc/releases") : 
  object 'magrittr_pipe' not found
```

Does anyone know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Try to install the package `magrittr`.

Comment: I already tried that but it is still showing the same error.